# How to get the name of attribute in python object?

Tags: python, object, attributes

For example I have next python class

```
class Myclass():
     a = int
     b = int
```

Imagine that I don't know the name this class, so I need to get **the names** of attributes? ("a" and "b")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want all (including private) attributes, just

```
dir(Myclass)
```

Attributes starting with `_` are private/internal, though. For example, even your simple `Myclass` will have a `__module__` and an empty `__doc__` attribute. To filter these out, use

```
filter(lambda aname: not aname.startswith('_'), dir(Myclass))
```